# Not able to apply the mobile server patch in WSO2 mobile server 1.0.0

Tags: wso2

I am configuring the wso2 mobile server for accessing an app from wso2 app manager.The steps at https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Integrating+a+Mobile+Device+Manager say to apply a patch by the command `patch -Np1 -d emm/ < emm-appm.patch`.This is not working for my linux machine.I have modified the command to point my EMM_HOME `patch -Np1 < emm-appm.patch`.The console says                                      `patching file api/appManager.js
can't find file to patch at input line 133
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:`
`|diff -rupN emm/api/deviceRouter.js emm-mod/api/deviceRouter.js
|--- emm/api/deviceRouter.js    2014-06-10 22:53:52.000000000 +0530
|+++ emm-mod/api/deviceRouter.js    2015-03-31 19:24:37.065589000 +0530`
`File to patch:`

Answer (score 0):

The above command is for EMM 1.1.0. 
The instructions for executing the command as as follows.

1. Copy the content in [1] to a file named **emm-appm.patch**
2. Copy the file to `wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps` folder
3. Navigate to `wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps` folder
4. Execute the command `patch -Np1 -d emm/ < emm-appm.patch`

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/45955719/emm-appm.patch?version=1&modificationDate=1430419323000&api=v2